# Debugging MBED with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, arm, mbed, gnu-toolchain

I am currently using mac OS to set up a debugger to debug Mbed OS application , I followed the instruction from https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.12/tutorials/eclipse.html .

I successfully set up the local debug toolchain and I am stuck at this error for quite awhile already. I install "make" as written in the documentary using homebrew and also set the path as suggested but still getting this error

> 00:13:27 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project mbed-os-example-blinky ****
> make all
> Cannot run program “make”: Unknown reason
> Error: Program “make” not found in PATH
> PATH=[/Users/roseyv/Developer/gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++]
> 00:13:27 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 4ms)

Any idea how to resolve this issue? or if there is any other better way we can set up debugger to debug MBED os application

Your help will be greatly appreciated, Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the mean time Mbed has updated their website. The link you posted is no longer valid. My suggestion now would be to use [Mbed Studio](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-studio/current/getting-started/index.html).

Unfortunately Mbed is moving away from supporting Eclipse and only supports IDE's for which you have to be logged in with your account, Mbed Studio or the online compiler.

You could build from the command line option. Next use something like a Segger j-link and [Segger Ozone](https://www.segger.com/products/development-tools/ozone-j-link-debugger/) to debug. I found Ozone easier to setup with random code compared to embedded debugging on Eclipse. This is what you pay for.